# SpringBoot Method has too many Body parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

I created feign client for call my RestApi. When I try to run my service I receive error from this requestMethod  `Method has too many Body parameters` For @RequestBody I used just Object type, becaues each time I can send another body request.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/v1/products/{product}/companies/{companyId}", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<Object> createProduct(URI baseUri,
                                         @HeaderParam("tenant-id") String tenantId,
                                         @PathVariable("product") String product,
                                         @PathVariable("companyId") String companyId,
                                         @RequestBody Object reqBody);
```

Comment: You cannot use `Object` as the type it needs to be a specific type else the serialization framework cannot know which object to use.

Comment: You can take requestbody as string and then parse as you want

Comment: You can use ObjectMapper to map the string to object also, depending on condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Object as the type, Please try to specify with our Class.The framework can't known which entity to use as response.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/v1/products/{product}/companies/{companyId}", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<MyEntity> createProduct(URI baseUri,
                                         @HeaderParam("tenant-id") String tenantId,
                                         @PathVariable("product") String product,
                                         @PathVariable("companyId") String companyId,
                                         @RequestBody Object reqBody);
```